# Trouble in deleting all sub-documents using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having a problem deleting all sub-documents from a MongoDB document using Mongoose.

This code is from a route using **Express.js**:

```
router.delete('/all', (req, res) => {
    Customers.update(
        {_id: req['customer']},
        {$pull: {addresses: {_id: {$exists: true}}}},
        {safe: true},
        (err, address) => { res.json(address); }
    );
});
```

This is what I'm trying, but nothing happens.There is other code that I was trying to use, that is:

```
router.delete('/all', (req, res) => {
    let customer = req['customer'];

    customer.addresses.forEach((doc, index) => {
        let address = customer.addresses[index];

        customer.addresses.remove(address._id);
        customer.save();
    });

    res.json({ok: 1});
});
```

But this code only remove a few sub-documents, not all, and I don't know why.

Comment: If you're removing everything from an array, couldn't you just $set it to [], instead of using $pull? E.g., `{$set: {addresses:[]}}`

Comment: I had 3 addresses, ran your code and only deleted two, ran the code again and deleted the last. Weird.